# System.Exception: 'Error getting printers' win 10/11

Tags: c#

I trying to print on a label printer from Dymo, 450 and 550 but when initialize i get an error in th class with init the printers. The error I get is
EntryPointNotFoundException: Kan ingangspunt met de naam SpoolMon_AddListener niet vinden in DLL PrintingSupportLibrary.dll.

Sorry Dutch

DYMO.LabelAPI.Windows.Printers.SpoolerMonitorGateway.SpoolerMonitorGateway() in SpoolerMonitorGateway.cs
DYMO.LabelAPI.Windows.PrinterDiscovery.WindowsDeviceDiscoveryAgent.CreateNewSpoolerMonitorGateway() in WindowsDeviceDiscoveryAgent.cs
DYMO.LabelAPI.Windows.PrinterDiscovery.WindowsDeviceDiscoveryAgent.WindowsDeviceDiscoveryAgent() in WindowsDeviceDiscoveryAgent.cs

stack:

```
DymoSDK.dll!DymoSDK.Implementations.DymoPrinter.GetPrinters()   Unknown
```

> VoorraadBeheer.exe!VoorraadBeheer.Classes.DymoPrinters.Initialize() Line 22 C#
> VoorraadBeheer.exe!VoorraadBeheer.DymoBarcodePrinter.DymoBarcodePrinter_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 51 C#

While debugging i get Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in DYMO.LabelAPI.PlatformSpecific.dll
in DymoSDK.App.Init();

the class where error appears:

```
using DymoSDK.Implementations;
using DymoSDK.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VoorraadBeheer.Classes
{
    public class DymoPrinters
    {
        public List<IPrinter> DymoPrinterList;

        private IDymoPrinter tmpIDymoPrinter;
        private IDymoLabel tmpIDymoLabel;
        public void Initialize()
        {
            DymoSDK.App.Init();
            tmpIDymoPrinter = DymoPrinter.Instance;
            tmpIDymoLabel = DymoLabel.Instance;
            DymoPrinterList = tmpIDymoPrinter.GetPrinters().Result.ToList();// ERROR here
        }

        public string LoadLabelXml(string LabelPath)
        {
            tmpIDymoLabel.LoadLabelFromFilePath(LabelPath);
            return tmpIDymoLabel.XMLContent;
        }

        public IDymoLabel MakeLabelFromXml(string LabelXml)
        {
            tmpIDymoLabel.LoadLabelFromXML(LabelXml);
            return tmpIDymoLabel;
        }
        public bool PrintLabel(IDymoLabel label, string PrinterName, int amount = 1)
        {
            return tmpIDymoPrinter.PrintLabel(label, PrinterName, amount).Result;
        }


    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help
Rinaldo

Enable and disable references but nothing help only a sleeples night

Comment: It is a typical DLL Hell problem.  The PrintingSupportLibrary.dll file that's included with [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DYMO.Connect.SDK/#readme-body-tab) has that export.  Run dumpbin.exe /exports on that dll to see for yourself.  Make sure you are not copying files from an old release of the library.

Comment: [Dynamo SDK](https://www.dymo.com/support?cfid=online-support-sdk) seems to have URLs to examples such as https://github.com/dymosoftware/DCD-SDK-Sample

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have the library (SDK), but is is possible your development machine does not have the driver software?!

https://www.dymo.com/support?cfid=user-guide

Comment: I have the newest program/drivers from the Dymo website. Same problem with another system.

Comment: there where 2 dll responsible for the error and the version they needed was worng.

Answer (score 0):

There where DLL's responsible who caused the problem. Also it important to use the right SkiaSharp libs, the right version

Comment: How did you isolate this? What is the right version of the SkiaSharp libraries? Without these details, this answer is unlikely to help future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: Took some time ton find your question. But if I get a error from a DLL i step into with F11 in Visual Studio and watch the error which DLL he called and don't find if the DLL has debug information. Skiashap dll's depend on the Dymo dll's